# LazyInitializationException on collection read after merge

Tags: hibernate

I'm converting an Eclipselink application to use Hibernate 3.6 bundled with JBoss 6 instead, and need to modify how lazy loading is done because of this. It is not my first time using hibernate.

However, it seems that my collections become uninitialized after a merge is done. I cannot remember seeing this behaviour ever before. For example:

```
Entity entity = entityDAO.getEntity(id);
System.out.println(entity.getMyCollection().size()); // OK, no exception
entity = entityDAO.update(entity);
System.out.println(entity.getMyCollection().size()); // Throws LazyInitializationException
```

EntityDAO snippet:

```
public Entity getEntity(Long id){
    Entity e = entityManager.find(Entity.class, id);
    Hibernate.initialize(e.getMyCollection());
    return e;
}

public Entity update(Entity entity){
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

Entity snippet:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="entity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<AnotherEntity> myCollection = new ArrayList<AnotherEntity>();
```

Is this really the expected behaviour? It seems very weird that hibernate would throw away data during merge..

Comment: I think your removed important part of your sample. Because "LazyInitializationException" thrown only if your left session somewhere between "update" and "entity.getMyCollection()".

Comment: Ah I should have clarified: this code exists completly outside the session in a managed bean. The real code is unnecessary complex since the real question was only if initialized collections are uninitialized after marge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed expected behavior. `merge()` consists in

- getting the entity with the same ID as the detached one passed as argument,
- copying the state of the detached entity to the attached one,
- and returning the attached entity

So, obviously, if you don't reinitialize the lazy collection of the returned attached entity, the collection won't be loaded.

Comment: * Coping the state of the detached entity to the attached one *. Should not this cascade to the collection due to cascade=CascadeType.ALL ?

Comment: I missed the cascade. But if nothing has been modified in the collection, I'm not sure Hibernate is forced to load the collection.